# Angular - Observable wrong boolean return statement

Tags: angular, rxjs

I dont know if I'm coding way too long today or I am missing out something obvious, but I have a method that should return a boolean observable:

```
  public canCreateStory(): Observable<boolean> {
     return this.isAuthenticated().pipe(tap(result => {
        console.log(result && this.authInstance.currentUser.emailVerified); <== prints out false
        return result && this.authInstance.currentUser.emailVerified;}));
  }
```

Now when I subscribe to that method, it prints out `true`:

```
  ngOnInit() {
     this.authService.canCreateStory().subscribe(result => console.log(result)) <== prints out true!?
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you subscribe, you are checking if there is a `result`. Since there is a value, it returns `true`! In the tap method however, you are checking for both `result` AND   `emailVerified` which seems to be false! Im pretty sure that in the `tap` function, if you console logged only  `result` you'd have `true`

Comment: You want to use `map` instead of `tap`. The `tap` operator ignores the returned value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to modify the value emitted by the observable, use `map` instead of `tap`:

```
public canCreateStory(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.isAuthenticated().pipe(
    map(result => result && this.authInstance.currentUser.emailVerified)
  );
}
```

From the RxJS documentation:

> [tap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap)
>
> Perform a side effect for every emission on the source Observable, but
>   return an Observable that is identical to the source.

> [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map)
>
> Applies a given project function to each value emitted by the
>   source Observable, and emits the resulting values as an Observable.